# Where are the non-scriptPubKey outputs in the chainstate leveldb?

Tags: transactions, script, output

I read 
https://bitcoindev.network/understanding-the-data/
and it explain that the leveldb of the chainstate contain transaction with at least one unspent output.

And it has "The scriptPubKey and amount for those unspent outputs."

But I read somewhere any OPCODE script is possible for an output.
Where are the non-scriptPubKey outputs?

Comment: A `scriptPubkey` is an "OPCODE script". See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Output

Answer (score 1):

They're the same thing. The `scriptPubKey` is the script in the transaction output.

Answer (score 0):

The scriptPubKey does not just contain public keys. It is specifically a script. The scrtipPubKey of an output is just the output script, so any arbitrary script in an output will be called the scriptPubKey. They are treated exactly the same as those scripts for pubkeys; there is no special distinction. Such outputs are stored in the chainstate database in the same way.